# How do I load custom configuration files with codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, configuration, codeigniter

I've just started to use codeigniter and I have a question.

I am using arrays for defining certain values like:

```
$gender = array ('male','female');
```

Or:

```
$maritalStatus = array ('married', 'single', 'divorced');
```

I am using these kind of arrays in different views. My question is, is there a chance to put all of these arrays in a configuration file and load it when I need it? Or is there another method to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just place all your variables in an array, and save that array in a separate config file in `system/application/config`.

Then, in your application code, load the config file like so:

```
$this->config->load($config_file);
```

Where `$config_file` is the name of your config file, without the `.php` extension.

Comment: Hey BoltClock,

Thank you for your answer. Now it's much more easy to orginze my code.

Thanks again.